# Perform 'Is one of' filter using Dynamics365 Odata filter

Tags: filter, odata, dynamics-365

When filtering in fields on D365, we have the filter option of '`is one of`' which is more like SQL's `where in` clause. I'm trying to perform such filter operation using Odata but can't find the right way. Lambda has an `any` and `all` but don't know how to throw in a list to compare against.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [In Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/in?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9).

`?$filter=Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.In(PropertyName=@p1,PropertyValues=@p2)&@p1='name'&@p2=['value','value']`

The full list of [filter's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/query-data-web-api#filter-results).

Comment: The in function doesn't work for the current version of odata which Dynamics 365 is on